# Create a unique id in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have created the formula shown in code's window to show "via" whenever[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4edoQ.jpg) there is more than one pickup consecutively.

It works great but whenever "Via" shows up in Crystal report, I want to display as Via1, Via2 ....etc.

```
`If {Command.ACTIVITY}= 'Pick' and 
(previousISNULL ({Command.PASSONBOARD}) or previous 
({Command.PASSONBOARD})="")
 and next ({Command.ACTIVITY})='Pick'
 then "Via"
  else ""`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable.

Try something like this:

```
shared numbervar counter;
If {Command.ACTIVITY}= 'Pick' and 
(previousISNULL ({Command.PASSONBOARD}) or previous 
({Command.PASSONBOARD})="")
 and next ({Command.ACTIVITY})='Pick'
 then counter := counter + 1;
 "Via" + cstr(counter)
```

Observe there are parenthesis in "then" clause.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, much appreciated. The provided formula works for me. Great! Also a quick question: Is it possible if the Via id displays to all rows belong to the same via id. Right now or in the provided screenshot it just shows with the first row.

Comment: Yes, it is. I edited the answer. Now, it always return the "via id". Notice that i removed the "else" clause.

Comment: Thank you again. It does not show the desired result. The outcomes are absolutely the same after removing else from the formula. Thx