# Repeat the value if belongs to same group

Tags: crystal-reports

[Possible outcomes of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5VxH.jpg)Hi all,
I am seeking some help to repeat the field name within the same group as shown in the image. I have used the following formula to create Via:

```
shared numbervar counter;
If {Command.ACTIVITY}= 'Pick' and 
(previousISNULL ({Command.PASSONBOARD}) or previous 
({Command.PASSONBOARD})="")
 and next ({Command.ACTIVITY})='Pick'
 then (
 counter := counter + 1;
 "Via" + cstr(counter))
  else ""
```

I would appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566846/create-a-unique-id-in-crystal-reports/56567269?noredirect=1#comment99716636_56567269). I updated the answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a unique id in crystal reports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566846/create-a-unique-id-in-crystal-reports)